# How to create hashmap from object by manipulating specific keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, hashmap

Trying for days to manipulate some JSON data response. How do I create a hashmap from the following?

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); //response that parced
```

For searching `"volvo, opel, honda`. After it's parsed, it returns per user indexed and looks like this (`jsonObject.length` changes in every different search):

```
[{user: 1, car: volvo, score:7, time: "some time"},{user: 2, car: volvo, score:8, time: "some time"},{user: 3, car: volvo, score:9, time: "some time"},{user: 3, car: opel, score:6, time: "some time"},{user: 3, car: honda, score:8, time: "some time"},{user: 4, car: volvo, score:6, time: "some time"},{user: 4, car: opel, score:7, time: "some time"},{user: 5, car: honda, score:8, time: "some time"}]
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
[{1:[7]},{2:[8]},{3:[9,6,8]},{4:[6,7]},{5:[8]}]
```

Comment: What is the structure of your jsonObject?

Comment: What do you mean "structure", i gave an example above, sorry for not understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array and collect all the scores for each user using an object to ensure you have unique user id's as keys

```js
const jsonObject = [
  {user: 1, car: 'volvo', score:7, time: "some time"}
, {user: 2, car: 'volvo', score:8, time: "some time"}
, {user: 3, car: 'volvo', score:9, time: "some time"}
, {user: 3, car: 'opel', score:6, time: "some time"}
, {user: 3, car: 'honda', score:8, time: "some time"}
, {user: 4, car: 'volvo', score:6, time: "some time"}
, {user: 4, car: 'opel', score:7, time: "some time"}
, {user: 5, car: 'honda', score:8, time: "some time"} 
]

const results = jsonObject.reduce((map, obj) => {
  // set a new key based on the user id if it doesn't exist
  if (!map.has(obj.user)) {
    map.set(obj.user, [])
  }
  // add to the users scores to the users score
  map.get(obj.user).push(obj.score)
  // return the accumulator
  return map
}, new Map)

for (let [key, value] of results.entries()) {
  console.log({
    key,
    value
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, very much. But i cannot irretate in the result.
If i store it in a var (e.x. myObject) the myObject[0] is undefined, not even mor inside in each array

Comment: @Panos it's an easy fix to put it into a map rather than an object, please see the updated code.

Comment: This is really great. For days i was trying to succeed the correct output into a map. Before your updated code i did what i want with sloppy way. JSON.stringify, str.replace, and JSON.parse again so the keys be strings.
Was ok for length <50 but NOT recommended for the results i get (over to 50.000). Thanks

Comment: @Panos glad it's working for you. It's much better to work with the data rather than regex with strings which is fraught with issues. If you are processing a large number of of results it might be worth chunking the results or using workers to do the processing so you aren't holding up the rest of you application, or better yet use something like MongoDB if this is a node app.

Answer (score 0):

**Using ES5**

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array, and use a helper object to set a reference to created objects by user name:

```js
var data = [{user: 1, car: 'volvo', score:7, time: "some time"},{user: 2, car: 'volvo', score:8, time: "some time"},{user: 3, car: 'volvo', score:9, time: "some time"},{user: 3, car: 'opel', score:6, time: "some time"},{user: 3, car: 'honda', score:8, time: "some time"},{user: 4, car: 'volvo', score:6, time: "some time"},{user: 4, car: 'opel', score:7, time: "some time"},{user: 5, car: 'honda', score:8, time: "some time"}];

var helper = {};
var result = data.reduce(function(r, o) {    
  if(!helper[o.user]) {
    helper[o.user] = {};
    r.push(helper[o.user]);
    helper[o.user][o.user] = [];
  }
  
  helper[o.user][o.user].push(o.score);
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

**Using ES6**

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the Map's [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) back to an array:

```js
const data = [{user: 1, car: 'volvo', score:7, time: "some time"},{user: 2, car: 'volvo', score:8, time: "some time"},{user: 3, car: 'volvo', score:9, time: "some time"},{user: 3, car: 'opel', score:6, time: "some time"},{user: 3, car: 'honda', score:8, time: "some time"},{user: 4, car: 'volvo', score:6, time: "some time"},{user: 4, car: 'opel', score:7, time: "some time"},{user: 5, car: 'honda', score:8, time: "some time"}];

const result = [...data.reduce((m, { user, score }) => {  
  const scores = m.get(user) || { [user]: [] };
  
  scores[user].push(score);
  
  return m.set(user, scores);
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain old JS method with no map, reduce or stuffs

```js
const data = [{"user":1,"car":"volvo","score":7,"time":"some time"},{"user":2,"car":"volvo","score":8,"time":"some time"},{"user":3,"car":"volvo","score":9,"time":"some time"},{"user":3,"car":"opel","score":6,"time":"some time"},{"user":3,"car":"honda","score":8,"time":"some time"},{"user":4,"car":"volvo","score":6,"time":"some time"},{"user":4,"car":"opel","score":7,"time":"some time"},{"user":5,"car":"honda","score":8,"time":"some time"}];

let res = []
data.forEach((item) => {
  if (res.length === 0) {
    res.push({[[item.user]]: [item.score]})
  }else {
    let index = -1;
    res.some((obj, i) => {
      if (Number(Object.keys(obj)[0]) === item.user) {
        index = i
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
    if (index !== -1) {
      res[index][item.user].push(item.score)
    } else {
      res.push({[item.user]: [item.score]}) 
    }
  }
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, and i can take the values of each array with myObject[i].values But do you now how can i take the myObject[i][key]?
The 1, 2 etc in the specific example.

Comment: Is there any way the value of user that becames the key at the new object (and is Number and not accessable) to become string "1" or "user_1", instead of just 1?